# Как можно узнать, что push-уведомление получено в iOS (Objective-C)?

Tags: ios, objective-c, apple, push-уведомления

Как можно узнать, что push-уведомление получено в iOS (Objective-C)?
Например, в android существует метод: onMessageReceived из com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmListenerService.

А в Objective-C - как это делается?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1623013-application?language=objc

Comment: https://habrahabr.ru/post/156811/

Comment: давайте вы все таки уточните, вам надо в приложении знать, что пришел пуш, или где то вне приложения?

Comment: Нужно, чтобы на удаленный сервер приходила информация о том, что сообщение с определенным id - доставлено.

Comment: тогда ответ ниже подходит

Answer (score 1):

На iOS нет возможности узнать о статусе Push-уведомления, к сожалению.

Однако, ты можешь добавить логики `-didReceiveRemoteNotification:` и `-didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`, чтобы на сервер уходили данные о том, что сообщение получено.